# Developing different Thematic Maps Feature for a web-application

Tags: java, html, css, github

I want to create a feature in a web-application with name "Attribute based map types". These are basically thematic maps feature in which a user can select the map from the available thematic maps at least 10. According to selected map type, input would be taken from user and will display on screen.

I am facing problems in libraries and plugins that how to execute them according to my requirements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is currently too broad and lacks necessary details. Please review the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide for more information about how to ask questions well. Also note that questions asking for libraries or plugins are not permitted on this forum.